# Yii2 - User Identity Secure?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-user

Is there any way a user can force switch his `Yii::$app->user->identity` without logging into another account?

During development I was logged in as user id #1. I made some design changes to the view then hit refresh then I was suddenly logged in as user id #3 (which I don't have the access details for)

I relogged and tried replicating the issue but it never happened again

Answer (score 1):

There is a method in Yii\web\User [setIdentity](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html#setIdentity%28%29-detail)

Comment: There's no place in my code where I call that. I do however have enableAutoLogin set to true. Does that allow users to login as a different person?

Comment: To me it never happened. You are using advanced templates?

Comment: Yes I'm using the advanced template

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you opened another session in other tab or window. Probably that was the issue. It never happened to me. If you want to force it you can use:

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html#switchIdentity()-detail

I have never use it personally, but it is available.